# timezone change not being detected in silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, date, datetime, timezone

**Base facts:**

- Silverlight 5 application (which means `TimeZoneInfo.ClearCachedDate()` is not supported).
- Application is on a client moving across multiple time zones.
- Dates are stored as UTC.

  - The UTC Offset of the client's time zone when the date/time value was saved is stored with the date/time value. This is done using the `TimeZoneInfo.Local.GetUTCOffset("value")` where value is the date/time value being saved.
  - Some dates are displayed using local client's time zone information. This is done using `DateTime.ToLocalTime()`.
  - Some dates must be displayed using the UTC offset to show the date/time as it was from the saving client's POV when it was saved ("static dates"). This is done using `DateTime.AddHours("stored offset value")` using the previously stored offset value.

**Scenario:**

When the application starts, it has the UTC offset from `TimeZoneInfo` correct for the client and everything displays correctly. However, when the time zone changes, the `DateTime.ToLocalTime()` displays appropriately to the changed-to time zone, but the `TimeZoneInfo.Local.GetUTCOffset` value does not change from the original time zone... in fact, `TimeZoneInfo` still displays the original time zone from application start, no matter how many time zone changes happen.

The only recourse is to close and restart the Silverlight application, which then correctly picks up the current time zone.

Because it is Silverlight, `TimeZoneInfo.ClearCachedData()` is unavailable to force a time zone refresh from the OS.

**Questions:**

- What other options are available to get the `TimeZoneInfo` to refresh without application restart?
- Should/Can I avoid `TimeZoneInfo` as a source of time zone information if it does not accurately contain the time zone info if the client moves across time zones?
- Any other people have encountered this, and how did you resolve/work around it?

Thanks!